# How to do substring in some elements of string list using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-stream, indexof

Below is my list of String.

```
["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thurs", "fri", "satur"]
```

I want to do remove "**day**" from the elements, if it is ending with "day".

Expected Output in the list:

```
["sun", "mon", "tues", "wednes", "thurs", "fri", "satur"]
```

**How to do this using Lambda?**

I have tried the below code, but was unable to assign the value to the list:

```
daysList.stream().forEach(s -> {
    if (s.endsWith("day")) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("day"));
    }
});
```

Comment: How about replacing `day` at the end with nothing, i.e. apply `String#replaceAll("day$", "")` to all elements. Just an idea how to get rid of the condition. If you can't write the changed elements back to the list (I don't know that API that well yet but "forEach" indicates it is not possible) you could collect them into a new list.

Comment: why don't you simply iterate over the list with a for loop?

Comment: @Thanigaiarasu I have done the same thing, you can see that in question. my question is after this operation my list should have elements without "day"

Comment: @wero Because he wants to know how to do this using a lambda?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most of the answers here make use of a Stream, but you should not be using a Stream at all:

```
daysList.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceFirst("day$", ""));
```

Answer (score 8):

Iterating over the stream using `forEach` won't work; you need to map each of the elements you modified to a new stream using `map`. Then you can collect the results back to your list.

```
daysList = daysList.stream()
        .map(s -> s.endsWith("day") ? s.substring(0, s.length()-3) : s)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Funny, my solution looked like yours :D. So I don't need to post it.

Comment: I think your `s.substring(0, s.indexOf("day"))` would be better written as `s.substring(0, s.length()-3)`; that way you don't run the risk of hitting an earlier occurrence of `"day"` in the string.

Comment: @khelwood Or better yet `lastIndexOf`. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @TNT better yet why? you're just performing an extra search that you already know the result of.

Comment: @khelwood You have a point. I was thinking more in terms of readability as if it would be easier to note that the range of the substring ends at the index of the last occurrence of "day". But like you said, that's already known, and that seems like a better solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> daysList = Arrays.asList("sunday", "monday", 
                                      "tuesday", "wednesday",
                                       "fri", "satur" 
                                      );


List<String> res = daysList.stream()
                            .map(s -> s.replace("day",""))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sub String with decimal points sorting** .

String arr[]=  {"2.4","4.2","3.1","5.7","3.0","2.01","7.06","6.003"};

List newList =Arrays.asList(arr);
newList.stream().map(n -> n.substring(n.indexOf('.')) ).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().sorted().forEach(n -> System.out.println(n));;